# How to style containers in boostrap with custom css?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to make the footer of my website. I want to change the style.

1) Can I create a custom stylesheet and include it into the footer file?

If yes, Do I need to create a new div for any element I want to choose or can use the class provide by Bootstrap?

For example, above I created a div and than in the style file I added #mydiv?

Or there is a better solution?

```
<div id="mydiv">
            <footer class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 30px;"> 

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/footer_logo.png"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/ico.png"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">xx</a>
            <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">xxx</a>
            <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">xxx</a>
            <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">xxx[enter image description here][1]</a>

            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">2004-2017. All 
          rights reserved.</div>
            </div>


            </footer>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Bootstrap classes you can apply your own like

```
<footer class="container-fluid my-custom-class" style="margin-top: 30px;">
```

Then just select this class in CSS and apply the styling you need. Be careful, as some attributes (like *width* ) can be overwritten by Bootstrap.

Hope this helps.